# Can I open a URL in a jqueryui dialog?

Tags: modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a contest entry site that requires a file upload to an external service. Right now, we just have a link to that external service, but we've found that even if we open the link in a separate tab/window, users sometimes forget to come back and complete the rest of our application. (This external service has no API for allowing us to do the uploads seamlessly from our site.)

My question: is it possible to use jquery's modal dialog to open an external URL? I'm not looking to control that URL in any way; I just want to keep the users on our main page while at the same time preventing them from being able to interact with the rest of our site until they've completed the upload.

**CODE**

Here's what I've got so far; it's currently returning "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." regardless of whether the link contains my URL or just plain google. Also, even though I have showCloseButton set to true and the height and width attributes set, it's ignoring those params.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#dropLink").click(function() {
            $.fancybox({
                            'padding'       : 0,
                            'modal'     : true,
                            'autoScale'     : false,
                            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                            'transitionOut' : 'none',
                            'title'     : 'Upload Video',
                            'width'     : 680,
                            'height'        : 495,
                            'showCloseButton'   : true,
                    });

            return false;
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>1. Visit <a id="dropLink" href="http://www.google.com">our dropbox</a> and upload your video file. Please enter &ldquo;Featured Exhibitor Program&rdquo; as the subject.</p> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) or *[any other lightbox plugin](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)*. Most of them allows you to show modal dialog with different website.

Edit:

try:

```
$("#dropLink").fancybox({
                'width' : '680px',
                'height' : '495px',
                'autoScale' : false,
                'transitionIn' : 'none',
                'transitionOut' : 'none',
                'type' : 'iframe'
            });
```

Comment: You should undo that "mark as answer" if you can. When I am reading your answer again, I am not sure that it will be that easy. Because you need some response from that site (which will tell you that process is done). You can get more answers (and maybe even more specific) if you leave this open until you get it working.

Comment: Thanks. I did try FancyBox, and it does open a box, but all it displays is text: "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later." When I open the same link in a plain browser tab, it works correctly. Is it possible for a site to prevent itself from being opened via script? (I'm a server-side programmer, so this UI stuff is pretty new to me.)

Comment: I am not sure, but I wouldn't say so. Those lightboxes usually just load target site into a iframe which basically behaves as a browser window afaik. But you can easily test it.. try to open google or any other site instead. You will see instantly where the problem is. Does your target site need loging in or is it secured in any way?

Comment: No, for the end user there's no login. I've tried setting my link to google, and I get the same result. I'm posting my full code in the OP right now.

Comment: I guess its because you have the modal option set to true.

Comment: Nope, I've tried true, false, and completely eliminating that param. Same results.

Comment: I have added some test code into my answer. But you will definitely have to go through their api, doumentation, tips and especially 'Example of callbacks' to see if you will be able to make it.

Comment: I've read through all of the documentation they offer on their site; I can't find anything that shows examples of callbacks...

Comment: has adding 'type': 'iframe' helped?

Answer (score 2):

We use [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) to open URLs into modals and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/) is another great solution for opening urls in modal box.